# Memory leaks with pandas upon exceptions

Tags: python, pandas, memory-leaks, pandas-groupby, jupyter

I run some library wrapped around pandas in Jupyter Lab.

Underlying dataframes are quite big (few Gb in RAM), and a lot of the processing based on iterations on subparts of the dataframes before concatenating subparts back together.

When developing with trial/error, it happens that the iteration raises an Exception on corner cases for subparts of the dataframe. Each time an exception is raised however, I see that memory usage starts increasing (htop), so I have to restart the kernel after too many exceptions have been raised.

For the latest exception, sys.last_traceback keeps handles on those big objects (for the latest exception), so I assume that handles to my big structures are kept somewhere, not only for the latest exception.

Any idea where to dig in?

Comment: `jupyter` may be keeping references to dataframes in its history.  But without seeing the run (which will be too much to copy-n-paste) it's hard to diagnose those details.

Comment: Thank you @hpaulj Indeed I suspect the `Out` object to hold references to all encountered exceptions with handles to all objects encountered in each frame. I will try to clear the Out dictionary with corresponding `_i` values and see if it helps...